# Transfer programs to another OS

Tags: package-management, opensuse, yum

I have openSUSE. I can install programs with `yum`.

```
yum install <progname>
```

I want to move my install to a new hard disk.
How can I transfer programs from one OS to another?

My problem is that I have no access to the internet. So how can I install a program on it?

Comment: Please clarify. Do you mean (1) you want to install the same package on multiple machines, but only download it once? (2) you want to list all the installed packages on machine A, and install them all on machine B, both running OpenSUSE; (3) you want to do the same, but machine B runs some other distro?; (4) you want to move your install to a new hard disk?; (5) something else

Comment: The easiest way, assuming you have a boot disc, is to just copy the drive, then resize the partition to be larger (assumably, your new disk is larger), then run resize2fs to enlarge the filesystem. Something like Clonezilla might automate this, don't recall...

Comment: Depending on what the answers to derobert's questions are, this might be a duplicate of [How to install exactly the same packages on another computer in openSUSE?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25995) or [Moving linux install to a new computer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2865)

Answer (score 3):

"opensuse" is not so much an operating system, but more likely a distribution (of linux). Whether you are able to transfer a program to another system depends more on the platform of the target system. Naturally not all libraries are available on all distributions. So, if you want to transfer one program to another system you may just copy it (comparable hardware assumed, 32bit, 64bit, x86 processor), or copy the package (rpm, deb, or just a tar file, perhaps gzipped), or you may transfer the sources and recompile it, which sometimes is the hard way but assures the best performance of the compiled program due to compiler optimization.
A totally other thing is to transfer a Linux-ELF or source to a not Linux-System, but this is perhaps (hopefully ;)) not what you want.